# error during compilation of a ARM64 android kernel

Tags: android, c, compilation, kernel

Even with deep researches i couldn't find the answer.
I'm compiling an Android ARM64 kernel, and in this file

> drivers/misc/qcom/qdsp6v2/audio_amrwbplus

i have those lines:

```
119 static long audio_ioctl(struct file *file, unsigned int cmd,
120                 unsigned long arg)
121 {
122 struct q6audio_aio *audio = file->private_data;
123 int rc = 0;

    ...
```

that throws this error:

```
drivers/misc/qcom/qdsp6v2/audio_amrwbplus.c: In function 'audio_ioctl_shared':
drivers/misc/qcom/qdsp6v2/audio_amrwbplus.c:121:13: error: invalid storage 
class for function 'audio_ioctl'
static long audio_ioctl(struct file *file, unsigned int cmd,
         ^
drivers/misc/qcom/qdsp6v2/audio_amrwbplus.c:121:1: warning: ISO C90 forbids 
mixed declarations and code [-Wdeclaration-after-statement]
error, forbidden warning: audio_amrwbplus.c:121
```

I'm compiling with both GCC 7.x and 5.x, both same result

Also i've tried to set

> -Wno-declaration-after-statement

into Makefile, with no luck

Comment: How do you compile it?

Comment: `export ARCH=arm64 && export CROSS_COMPILE=../uber-7.x/bin/aarch64-linux-android- && make name_defconfig && make`
Standard is -std=89

Comment: Remove `-std=89`

Comment: `-std=89` is into the Makefile, should i remove it anyway?

Comment: Apparently the code is not conforming this standard version.

Comment: Without using std=89 i get many more errors, i do need to fix that code in order to compile the whole kernel with standard C89

Comment: Is this your code or some third party that you have added to a vanilla kernel?

Comment: That file is the same as stock vanilla

Comment: Federico Benedetti -std=c99 I do not understand the reason of the ancient standard used, if the source is written according to newer one I do not believe Android ARM64 to be C89. Many of the develpers of it were not even planned at that time

Comment: Unfortunately all kernels are made with -std=gnu89, even lastest 4.4.y are like that
Do you know how to fix that error?

Answer (score 0):

For everyone with the (kind of) same problem, this is the solution.

The issue wasn't those lines that the compilator was telling me, but (in the same file) some lines before that. It was just some weird placed parenthesis, that were messing with the code after.

If you got something like this, try to search deeper on the same file, you'll probably find something wrong with logic that is messing.